# Big O of accessing a string with an index in Swift 3.0

Tags: swift

What is the complexity of accessing a `String` with an `index` in `swift` 3.0?

Is the complexity the same as array access or O(N) or something else?

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html) under "String Indices":

```
let greeting = "Guten Tag!"
let index = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: 7)
greeting[index]
.
.
.
for index in greeting.characters.indices {
    print("\(greeting[index]) ", terminator: "")
}
// Prints "G u t e n   T a g ! "
```

The last example (iterating over the characters) would be pretty terrible if indexed access was O(N) since just iterating over the characters that way would be O(n^2)

The reason why I am unsure is the following statement: "different characters [...] can require different amounts of memory to store".

If the complexity is anything other than O(n), how does that work, since one can't just multiply an offset by a constant to get to the character in memory?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unless documented otherwise, an implementation of `Collection`'s [`subscript`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1641358-subscript) requirement *should* always have an O(1) time complexity. It's part of the contract with `Collection` itself.

As [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection) states (emphasis mine):

> Types that conform to `Collection` are expected to provide the `start​Index` and `end​Index` properties **and subscript access to elements as O(1) operations**. Types that are not able to guarantee that expected performance must document the departure [...]

The potentially expensive part happens when you come to *advance* indices, such as with [`index(_:offsetBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1781645-index). The complexity for this is O(1) for a `RandomAccessCollection`, O(n) otherwise, where n is the magnitude of the offset.

[`String.CharacterView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/string.characterview) isn't a `RandomAccessCollection`, therefore advancing indices is O(n). As you say, the reason for this is that characters can have different byte lengths. But once you have the index ([which internally](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/StringCharacterView.swift#L169) is just an offset value for the string's unicode scalars along with the length of the given extended grapheme cluster in UTF-16 code units), you can subscript in constant time.

Therefore

```
for index in greeting.characters.indices {
    print("\(greeting[index]) ", terminator: "")
}
```

is O(n). Each iteration of the loop simply advances the current index by 1, and the subscript uses the index's offset to jump to the start of the extended grapheme cluster and therefore get the character for that given index.

If however we said:

```
for offset in 0..<greeting.characters.count {
    let index = greeting.index(greeting.startIndex, offsetBy: offset)
    print("\(greeting[index]) ", terminator: "")
}
```

*That* would be O(n<sup>2</sup>), because we're now advancing the index from the start index at each iteration of the loop (not to mention doing an O(n) walk just to get the `count` of the characters to begin with).

Comment: Deleted my one, misunderstood the question, Nice explanation mate :)

Comment: I've read the documentation on `RandomAccessCollection` but still don't get it. Only thing I got was that _the index for your custom type must conform to the Strideable_ does that mean that anything that is accessible by an integer subscript conforms to this? And things like dictionaries/Strings (in Swift4 which are similar to String.CharacterView) don't ?

Comment: @Honey The index for a random access collection does not have to conform to `Strideable` – the documentation just says that doing so is one way to ensure you meet the complexity guarantees (as `Strideable` requires constant time advancement). So yes, if your index type is `Strideable` (such as `Int`), then you should really be a `RandomAccessCollection`. Things like dictionaries and strings use opaque index types in order to prevent you from advancing them yourself without using the designated collection methods for doing so.

Comment: You just said what's not its requirement. Not what it is :) Can you elaborate what `RandomAccessCollection` is?

Comment: @Honey A random access collection is a `BidirectionalCollection` where indices are advanced (and measured) in O(1) time :) Take for example the `count` property – it has a default implementation that measures the difference between `startIndex` and `endIndex`. For random access collections such as `Array`, `count` is O(1) because we can measure the distance between `endIndex` and `startIndex` in O(1) time. But for types like `String`, advancing an index by `n` places is O(n), because characters can have different encoded byte lengths. So count is O(n) and it is not a random access collection.

Comment: (that being said, it is possible to have an O(1) count and not be a random access collection, for example you could store the count directly)

Comment: I completely get it now why for an array it's `O(1)`. For String, do you mean because it does't have a `startIndex` / `endIndex` then it's not `O(n)`?

Comment: String does have a `startIndex` and `endIndex`, but measuring the distance between them is O(n)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182742/discussion-between-honey-and-hamish).