# Custom Collections Without Internal Collection Types?

Tags: swift, data-structures, collections

I'd like to learn more about [Swift's Collection Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) by creating a custom collection.

The problem is that I can't find any examples of "custom" collection types that don't just use an internal array / dictionary.

These aren't helpful to me, because when it comes time to conform to the collection protocol, the examples just propagate the required methods to the army / dictionary.

That said, after looking through Wikipedia's [List of Data Structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_data_structures), I can't find any that meet the performance characteristics of collection types, that aren't just specialized arrays.

Does anyone know of a data structure that could be implemented with a custom collection type, without using an internal collection type?

EDIT

Collection protocol conformance requires that accesing the startIndex, the endIndex,and the elements of the collection be done constant time - O(1).

EDIT 2

The consensus in the comments seems to be that a [LinkedList](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) is a data structure that satisfies these characteristics. My LinkedList is defined as follows:

```
indirect enum LinkedList<T> {
    case value(element: T, next: LinkedList<T>)
    case end
}

extension LinkedList: Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> LinkedListIterator<T> {
        return LinkedListIterator(current: self)
    }
}

struct LinkedListIterator<T>: IteratorProtocol {
    var current: LinkedList<T>
    mutating func next() -> T? {
        switch current {
        case let .value(element, next):
            current = next
            return element
        case .end:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

What I still don't understand, is how `subscript` can be returned in constant time. For the LinkedList:

```
let data = LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 0, next: LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 1, next: LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 2, next: LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 3, next: LinkedList<Int>.end))))
```

Assume that I want access to the 3rd element in the Collection:

```
let example = data[2]
```

Currently, this is how I have implemented subscript:

```
subscript (position: Index) -> Element {
    precondition(position < endIndex && position >= startIndex)
    var iterator = makeIterator()
    for i in 0 ..< position {
        iterator.next()
        if i + 1 == position {
            return iterator.next()!
        }
    }
    var zero = makeIterator()
    return zero.next()!
}
```

Because the method's completion time depends on `i, it finishes in linear rather than constant time. How could such a constant time method be implemented?

Comment: A linked list maybe? Does that satisfy what you want?

Comment: Here is an example of a "minimal" Collection type: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668635/swift-minimum-implementation-for-types-conforming-to-protocols-with-default-impl.

Comment: Just a note on "*the elements of the collection be done constant time*"; while `Collection` requires the *subscript* implementation to operate in constant time; *advancing* an index by n positions can happen in linear time (but constant time for a `RandomAccessCollection`). So for example if you implement a linked list, you need to ensure that it's the index advancement that walks through the list, not the subscript implementation.

Comment: Here is an example of an AVL tree implementing the Collection protocol: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133349/a-generic-avl-tree-with-sequencetype-collectiontype-and-arrayliteralconvertible (written in an older version of Swift).

Comment: @Hamish So, in the example of a linkedList, I could iterate through the list to return the subscript? I don't quite see how one can return a subscript without advancing the index.

Comment: @Sweeper That is what I used to conform to the Sequence protocol, but I don't know if it will work for Collection as well. My concern is that I don't see a way for a subscript to be returned in a linkedList without first iterating through its elements, which would be linear, rather than constant time.

Comment: @BrandonBradley One way of implementing a linked list would be to have the index type hold a reference to a given node in the list. Then when you advance the index, you advance to the next node. When you come to subscript, you simply access the element at the given node held by the index.

Comment: @Hamish When is the index advancing? In a collection, shouldn't the code  `instanceOfCollection[8]`  return the eight element in constant time? If so, how can the index already be advanced to the eighth position?

Comment: @BrandonBradley Index advancing happens with the collection's indexing methods such as `index(after:)`, `index(_:offsetBy:)`, `index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)` etc. With a linked list, you wouldn't have an integer index, you would want your own custom (probably opaque) index type that holds a reference to a node of the list. To get the 8th element in the list, you would say `linkedList[linkedList.index(linkedList.startIndex, offsetBy: 8)]`. `linkedList.index(_:offsetBy:)` runs in linear time with respect to the offset, the `subscript` itself runs in constant time.

Comment: @BrandonBradley This is important btw to prevent accidently quadratic code; for example consider `var i = startIndex; while i < endIndex { print(self[i]); formIndex(after: &i) }`. If subscripting took linear time, this loop (which looks linear), would be accidently quadratic. [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42926871/2976878) may be useful.

Comment: @Hamish: Doesn't the Index have to be Comparable? Comparing pointers would not give the corresponding order of collection elements.

Comment: @MartinR Yes, a `Collection`'s `Index` has to be `Comparable` (in constant time). Implementing that for a linked list would require the index to maintain an internal offset of some description in order to determine whether it comes before another index.

Comment: Another problem could be to implement proper value semantics (unless you define the LinkedListCollection as a class). That's what this question https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/133141/35991 on Code Review was about. Unfortunately, the link to the code gist in the comments does not work anymore.

Comment: Been busy @MartinR :) That being said, IMO OP's question is too broad as it currently is (as it doesn't specify a specific collection type they're trying to implement); if it were narrowed down to more "I'm trying to implement a linked list, but don't see how it can meet collection's time complexity requirements", then I'd be happy to drop an answer.

Comment: @Hamish I narrowed the scope of the question, and posted my current implementation, which uses an O(n) subscript.

Comment: @BrandonBradley Thanks – I'll try and post an answer later today :)

Comment: @Hamish: Apparently, a (refined?) version of the problem has been posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45615582/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR: Thanks for me letting me know :) OP: Sorry, I was always planning on coming back to this, but never got round to it! I guess you should delete this one and we can focus on your new question, given the new one is more refined? If so, I'll try and post an answer to *that* one when I can, that is, if someone doesn't beat me to it :)