# How to Return subscript in Constant Time?

Tags: swift, collections, time-complexity

As per the [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/collection) when conforming to the `Collection` protocol:

> Types that conform to Collection are expected to provide the startIndex and endIndex properties and subscript access to elements as O(1) operations.

How can subscript be returned in constant time? Wouldn't it need to iterate through the collection, up to the correct index, and then return that value?

This is the LinkedList that I'm using to conform to `Collection`:

```
indirect enum LinkedList<T> {
    case value(element: T, next: LinkedList<T>)
    case end
}

extension LinkedList: Sequence {
    func makeIterator() -> LinkedListIterator<T> {
        return LinkedListIterator(current: self)
    }
    var underestimatedCount: Int {
        var count = 0
        for _ in self {
            count += 1
        }
        return count
    }
}

struct LinkedListIterator<T>: IteratorProtocol {
    var current: LinkedList<T>
    mutating func next() -> T? {
        switch current {
        case let .value(element, next):
            current = next
            return element
        case .end:
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

And here is this is where I actually conform to the protocol:

```
extension LinkedList: Collection {

    typealias Index = Int
    typealias Element = T

    var startIndex: Index {
        return 0
    }
    var endIndex: Index {
        return underestimatedCount
    }
    func index(after i: Index) -> Index {
        return (i < endIndex) ? i + 1 : endIndex
    }
    subscript (position: Index) -> Element {
        precondition(position < endIndex && position >= startIndex)
        var iterator = makeIterator()
        for i in 0 ..< position {
            iterator.next()
            if i + 1 == position {
                return iterator.next()!
            }
        }
        var zero = makeIterator()
        return zero.next()!
    }

}

let test = LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 2, next: LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 4, next: LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 7, next: LinkedList<Int>.value(element: 9, next: LinkedList<Int>.end))))
```

Comment: You can have a look at [Collection's source code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Collection.swift) to see how it is implemented in Swift itself. For a more practical, less theoretical tutorial on the topic, you can also check [this tutorial by raywenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/139591/building-custom-collection-swift)

Comment: Note that `underestimatedCount` should be O(1) as well.

Comment: Default implementation of `Collection` methods are assuming O(1) subscript, so if you make your `LinkedList` conform to `Collection`, you'll find some of them are too slow.

Comment: I think `Collection`s are some things like an array, whose elements can be accessed randomly, and a `LinkedList` is a `Sequence` rather than a `Collection` to me.

Comment: @NandiinBao That's `RandomAccessCollection` you're thinking of; a collection that can have its indices offset in constant time, as well as measuring the distance between two indices in constant time. A `Collection` is just a `Sequence` that can be iterated over nondestructively, and has an index that you can subscript with. Offsetting an index by `n` places can take place in O(n) time (but the *subscript* is expected to have an O(1) implementation).

Comment: @DávidPásztor I tried that, but the `Bag` uses an internal `Collection` that is used for `Collection` conformance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The collection's `Index` does not have to be an `Int`. One possible approach
is to use a custom index type which has a *reference* to the corresponding
element. However this requires the list nodes to be instances of a class.

Here is something that I came up with. It can probably be improved,
but hopefully demonstrates the idea.

`class ListNode` stores
the element and a pointer to the next node, and in addition, an increasing
integer `ordinal`, which is used to make `struct ListIndex` 
adopt the `Comparable` protocol.

`struct ListIndex` contains a reference to the list node, or `nil`
for `endIndex`.

```
struct LinkedListCollection<T>: Collection {

    class ListNode {
        let element: T
        let next: ListNode?
        let ordinal: Int

        init(element: T, next: ListNode?, ordinal: Int) {
            self.element = element
            self.next = next
            self.ordinal = ordinal
        }

        // Create ListNode as the head of a linked list with elements from an iterator.
        convenience init?<I: IteratorProtocol>(it: inout I, ordinal: Int = 0) where I.Element == T {
            if let el = it.next() {
                self.init(element: el, next: ListNode(it: &it, ordinal: ordinal + 1), ordinal: ordinal)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

    struct ListIndex: Comparable {
        let node: ListNode?

        static func <(lhs: ListIndex, rhs: ListIndex) -> Bool {
            // Compare indices according to the ordinal of the referenced
            // node. `nil` (corresponding to `endIndex`) is ordered last.

            switch (lhs.node?.ordinal, rhs.node?.ordinal) {
            case let (r?, l?):
                return r < l
            case (_?, nil):
                return true
            default:
                return false
            }
        }

        static func ==(lhs: ListIndex, rhs: ListIndex) -> Bool {
            return lhs.node?.ordinal == rhs.node?.ordinal
        }
    }

    let startIndex: ListIndex
    let endIndex: ListIndex

    // Create collection as a linked list from the given elements.
    init<S: Sequence>(elements: S) where S.Iterator.Element == T {
        var it = elements.makeIterator()
        startIndex = ListIndex(node: ListNode(it: &it))
        endIndex = ListIndex(node: nil)
    }

    func index(after i: ListIndex) -> ListIndex {
        guard let next = i.node?.next else {
            return endIndex
        }
        return ListIndex(node: next)
    }

    subscript (position: ListIndex) -> T {
        guard let node = position.node else {
            fatalError("index out of bounds")
        }
        return node.element
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
let coll = LinkedListCollection(elements: [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13])
for idx in coll.indices {
    print(coll[idx])
}
```